# Control naming conventions in Caliburn.Micro framework

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, naming-conventions, caliburn.micro

Caliburn.Micro allows configuring naming conventions for views and view models, but I couldn't find how to configure matching between controls and methods. I know I can just use `Message.Attach` attached property, but I'd like to rely on conventions if it's possible.

Caliburn.Micro's conventions say that methods must be named the same as controls. But here lies a problem: they are often named differently. For example, `Save` and `Cancel` are good names for methods, but bad names for buttons. `SaveButton` and `CancelButton` are good names for buttons, but bad names for methods. Considering XAML is less strictly typed than C#, Hungarian notation can be useful too, but names like `btnSave` and `btnCancel` are unacceptable for methods.

The closest thing I could find is `ConventionManager.GetPropertyCaseInsensitive`, but it only works for properties, not for methods.

**Question**: How to configure Caliburn.Micro's conventions to make it attach `Save` method to `SaveButton` control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't something I've tried before, but if you have a look at the [Documentation](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Conventions), there's the mention of a `ViewModelBinder` class that's responsible for fixing up the various bindings of properties, methods, etc. to their respective `ViewModels`.

Of particular interest in your case:

> ViewModelBinder.BindActions is a Func and thus can be entirely
>   replaced if desired. Adding to or changing the ElementConventions via
>   the ConventionManager will also effect how actions are put together.
>   More on that below.

So essentially, it should be possible to get the behaviour you're after, by defining your own `BindActions` function.

As a place to start, you can look at the [source](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/ViewModelBinder.cs) for the `ViewModelBinder.BindActions` and see how the function is currently defined.

If you cut out the WinRT specific code, you're left with something that looks like this (You'll probably have to remove the Log calls):

```
ViewModelBinder.BindActions =
(namedElements, viewModelType) =>
{

    var methods = viewModelType.GetMethods();
    var unmatchedElements = namedElements.ToList();

    foreach (var method in methods)
    {
        var foundControl = unmatchedElements.FindName(method.Name);

        if (foundControl == null)
        {
            Log.Info("Action Convention Not Applied: No actionable element for {0}.", method.Name);
            continue;
        }

        unmatchedElements.Remove(foundControl);

        var message = method.Name;
        var parameters = method.GetParameters();

        if (parameters.Length > 0)
        {
            message += "(";

            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                var paramName = parameter.Name;
                var specialValue = "$" + paramName.ToLower();

                if (MessageBinder.SpecialValues.ContainsKey(specialValue))
                    paramName = specialValue;

                message += paramName + ",";
            }

            message = message.Remove(message.Length - 1, 1);
            message += ")";
        }

        Log.Info("Action Convention Applied: Action {0} on element {1}.", method.Name, message);
        Message.SetAttach(foundControl, message);
    }

    return unmatchedElements;
};
```

You can see that the `Caliburn.Micro` attempts to bind the method to the control by comparing the available method names on the `ViewModel` with the names of the controls present within the corresponding `View`.

One approach could be to simply add second attempt to find a control, searching the method names with `Button` appended. That seems slightly counter-intuitive (it makes more logical sense to strip button from the name).

```
if (foundControl == null)
{
    // Check again for "<Method>Button" named FrameworkElements
    foundControl = unmatchedElements.FindName(method.Name + "Button");

    if (foundControl == null)
    {
        Log.Info("Action Convention Not Applied: No actionable element for {0}.", method.Name);
        continue;
    }
}
```

Obviously, this would mean if you had a control named `SaveButton` and one named `Save`, only one which was last encountered would be wired up correctly. The solution depends on whether or not you want to retain the original binding behaviour as well, or just this new behaviour.

It's worth reading that entire documentation link in either case, as it mentions additional things of interest like the `ViewModelBinder.ApplyConventionsByDefault` flag.